# Photoshop: how to draw a moon-like shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, drawing

How would I draw something like this in Photoshop and put it above some text?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us your attempts and tell us why you don't like the results?

Answer (score 3):

Best thing to do is create 2 circles and subtract one from the other

- Create a new layer.
- Use the Marquee Tool and hold down Shift to create a round selection.
- Hit D and Alt+Backspace to fill this with black.
- Duplicate the layer and move the new layer down holding Shift.
- Left click the other layer and hit Delete.

If this sounds confusing see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aMmuEq6hAE) which describes something similar using shapes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work very well! One question though, how can you make that transparent? If I set fill to transparent, it just shows through

Comment: Seems like you're just learning Photoshop and hope we don't turn this into a tutorial? :) You can set a layer's transparency in a number of ways. The easiest is to just press 1, 2, 3, etc which translate to 10%, 20%, 30% etc transparency.

Comment: I really get what you mean and it works perfectly, but what I meant was that my logo is transparent and when I overlap the 2nd ellipse and set the fill to transparent, the 1st will shine through. If I set it to white it works but the logo is not transparent anymore. I have tried to google how to make a transparent fill but all they seem to suggest is setting  fill to 0%

Comment: Google and Youtube this again until you are left with a single moon shape, not 2 ellipses. You don't need 2 shapes for this.

Comment: oh, I hadnt realized. Sorry for the trouble and thanks a lot for the great help, I'll try to up my google skills.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a curve using the pen tool. Position the Pen tool where you want the curve to begin, and hold down the mouse button.
The first anchor point appears, and the Pen tool pointer changes.

Drag to set the slope of the curve segment you’re creating, and then release the mouse button.
In general, extend the direction line about one third of the distance to the next anchor point you plan to draw.

Also you can get more help from https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! Problem I have is that it will be very 'unclean',like my paths are not exact. Is there any other way to do this? Or can you maybe download it somewhere?